# 10+ Years Old Website are Suddenly Showing 404 Cache Error

Tags: cache

I am getting 404 errors while checking caching of old websites.
I have research on this issue and found that Google may be collecting data for mobile index and i have check server log as well and found Google bot is visiting every day on my site but caching is not available of websites.

There are some references which i found for this issue research:
Cache bug of not caching, Ajay have shared the reference:
https://searchengineland.com/google-makes-some-clarifications-related-to-mobile-first-indexing-300199 
[image]

Tracking of Mobile First Index Activity:

https://www.seoclarity.net/blog/monitor-google-moved-site-mobile-first-index-17633/

https://www.seroundtable.com/google-cache-returns-404-error-seo-25565.html

I am still in the middle of this issue and it is not get resolved.

Comment: We're getting quite a few questions about this lately (see the second linked question above). As you noted, it's something Google needs to resolve, so you'll need to wait for that to occur.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I also got this issue before it get resolved and i was not able to research enough but this time i have seen multiple website are showing 404 so i do research on this topic and got lots of solutions now waiting for positive Google result.